# Automatic style checking for Android projects

Tags: java, javascript, android, coffeescript, checkstyle

For javascript, coffeescript and ruby projects there is [Hound CI](https://houndci.com) a service by thoughtbot which allows the bot to comment on Pull Requests detecting style violations. Is there something similar for Android Projects, or even Java? I am running [checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net) locally to check for style issues but looking at a diff in GitHub and commenting on it for style violations seems kind of dumb.

Comment: Check out [Lint](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html). ALso there is lint plugin for eclipse.

Comment: Lint already exists in Android Build Tools, specifically wanted to know if there is some cloud hosted version of it which can comment on Pull Requests in Github

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven or Gradle there are plugins that you can use with something like Travis CI:

- [Violation Comments to GitHub Gradle Plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violation-comments-to-github-gradle-plugin).
- [Violation Comments to GitHub Maven Plugin](https://github.com/tomasbjerre/violation-comments-to-github-maven-plugin).

If you are Jenkins, there is a plugin for that:

- [Violation Comments to GitHub Jenkins Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/violation-comments-to-github-jenkins-plugin).